# How to set the default option in SELECT input field

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to set the default value for a SELECT element but it's not working. This is my code:

```
 $enum_options = array('1'=>__('None'), '2'=>__('Call for Interview'),'3'=>__('Rejected'),'4'=>__('Pending for Upcoming Oportunities'));
 echo $record['Record']['status'];
 echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=> $enum_options, 'default' => $record['Record']['status']));
```

The status field in the DB is type ENUM:

```
 `status` enum('None','Call for Interview','Rejected','Pending for Upcoming Oportunities') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
```

Any help? Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: What is `$record['Record']['status'];` ?

Comment: Is just to check which value is stored in that var. For example I get "Rejected" instead the numeric value (1,2,3,4) maybe for this isn't working by I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: yes, but he probably wants to know that the status currently is? what is the exact output? if it is 0 then you know what the problem is

Comment: Nop, it's 2 I mean array_search($record['Record']['status'], $enum_options) returns "2" so this is not the problem

Comment: FWIW, pressing refresh in Firefox won't allow you to test whether default values are working. You need to put your cursor in the URL bar and press enter (or view the source).

Comment: I've already try that even cleaning the cache complety :( and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$enum_options = array('1'=>__('None'), '2'=>__('Call for Interview'),'3'=>__('Rejected'),'4'=>__('Pending for Upcoming Oportunities'));
if($record['Record']['status'] == 'Call for Interview'){
 echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=> $enum_options, 'selected' => '2'));
}else if($record['Record']['status'] == 'Rejected'){
 echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=> $enum_options, 'selected' => '3'));
}else if($record['Record']['status'] == 'Pending for Upcoming Oportunities'){
 echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=> $enum_options, 'selected' => '4'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would never use the view to set default values.
this is part of the logic and should be inside the controller action

so in your case

```
if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
    $this->request->data['Record']['status'] = 2;
}
```

etc

Also note that Cake itself doesnt really support ENUM. your approach has several downsides and limitations.
A more suitable and extendable solution is http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

Comment: I've try that solution and doesn't work for me, any other advice even if I need to change my DB structure? I'm stucked here :(

Comment: what do you mean with it doesnt work? it works perfectly in more than 10 apps :) and is easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

use "empty". this will work perfect.

```
$enum_options = array('1'=>'None', '2'=>'Call for Interview', '3'=>'Rejected', '4'=>'Pending for Upcoming Oportunities');

echo $this->Form->input('status', array('type'=>'select', 'label'=>'Status', 'options'=> $enum_options, 'empty'=>$record['Record']['status']));
```

Comment: This works too but repeat the element twice meaning if I have 'Rejected' then 'Rejected' appears selected but appear once again below ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple 2 line tricks.. Surely it will work

```
$enum_options = array('1'=>__('None'), '2'=>__('Call for Interview'),'3'=>__('Rejected'),'4'=>__('Pending for Upcoming Oportunities'));

 echo $this->Form->input('status', array('label' => __('Status'),'options'=> $enum_options, 'selected' => !empty($record['Record']['status'])?$enum_options[$record['Record']['status']]:1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the name of your form. It will determine what the record should be named in order to get it to default. To have the status default to the record you are pulling from the database, you would do something like this:

```
<?php
   echo $this->Form->create('MODELNAME');
   echo $this->Form->input('status', array('options'=> $enum_options));
?>
```

Then in the controller, make sure your record is set correctly:

```
$this->request->data['MODELNAME']['status'] = #;
```

Notice how both the record and the Form->create MODELNAME match. This is a must in order for the default value to automatically be selected. Then all you need to do is set # to the number value of the option you want set as the default.